# Why does os/exec command not work as expected when passed argument is the output of previously run exec?

Tags: go, exec

I'm trying to open the given URL on the browser using **golang**. When I use this code, it works as expected and opens the given URL in the browser:

```golang
func main() {
    url := "https://google.com"

    fmt.Printf(url)

    cmd := exec.Command("open", url)

    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    err := cmd.Run()
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    }
}
```

outputs (opens the browser):

```sh
~/workspace/go/so ❯ go run main.go
https://google.com%
```

But when I use the output of `exec.Command("echo", "https://google.com")` as the argument of the second `exec.Command` call then program returns an error as below:

```golang
func main() {
    output, err := exec.Command("echo", "https://google.com").Output()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    url := string(output)

    fmt.Printf(url)

    cmd := exec.Command("open", url)

    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    err = cmd.Run()
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    }
}
```

output (there is current directory path as a behind URL in the error):

```sh
~/workspace/go/so ❯ go run main.go
https://google.com
exit status 1: The file /Users/kadir/workspace/go/so/https:/google.com
 does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong in the second code block?

---

my **go version is 1.17** and `go.mod` file is this:

```golang
module so

go 1.17

require github.com/urfave/cli/v2 v2.3.0

require (
    github.com/cpuguy83/go-md2man/v2 v2.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/russross/blackfriday/v2 v2.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name v1.0.0 // indirect
)
```

Comment: `exec.Command` is working fine, but `open` is trying to open the argument as a file, perhaps because you put a new line at the end of the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JimB noted there's an implicitly newline at the end of the command output.

It's a good practice to use the `fmt` `%q` verb to ensure output does not have rogue characters:

```
 fmt.Printf("%q\n", url)  // "https://google.com\n"
```

So fix this either at the source, using `echo -n` to suppress the newline:

```
output, err := exec.Command("echo", "-n", "https://google.com").Output()
```

or on the receiving end:

```
url = strings.TrimSpace(url)
```